# Error in Cordova: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_cordovaNative'

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, cordova

I am developing a hybrid app with Cordova, and when I launch it using Android Studio, I encounter the following error in the console:

````
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_cordovaNative')
    at cordova.js:340:22
    at build (cordova.js:47:9)
    at require (cordova.js:62:24)
    at localRequire (cordova.js:43:20)
    at cordova.js:932:25
    at build (cordova.js:47:9)
    at require (cordova.js:62:24)
    at localRequire (cordova.js:43:20)
    at Object.bootstrap (cordova.js:1420:20)
    at cordova.js:1281:32

```
`
When i do Cordova run browser it works perfect, but not with cordova run android.
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.